# replication of control in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating a dynamic control by calling partial view.[image: my layout looks like this]

When I change the value of dropdown at first time it works fine. But when I change the value of dropdown at second or more time i get replication of controls the number of times.

The jquery i used to append the division is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addItem").live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //        $("#mydiv").html("");
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: "Get",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (srcc) {
                $("#mydiv").append(srcc);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and my controller look like :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BlankEditorRow()
{
    TempData["PassedDivision"] = extract.getDivision();
    TempData["Country"] = extract.getCountry();
    return PartialView("ViewUserControl1");
}
```

The code for actionlink is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add another", "BlankEditorRow", "HREduInformation", new { id = "addItem" })
```

Where am I going wrong?Thankx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script tag is in the markup for the partial view, look at the rendered html in a browser and make sure that script is not being duplicated.  Your javascript code is not wrapped in a function, so as soon as the script is loaded by your browser, it is executed.

Comment: thnx i wrapped in a function and found that  .append is creating problem here .I tried using html it workd bt only one dynamic control can be genetated.How do I fix this?